# How to display query results from a database in HTML using node.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I am currently creating a webpage with node.js that makes queries to a MySQL database and displays the results in a table.

I want the page to display all the data in the database upon initial loading, but I also want to implement a filter where the user can fill in some fields and when the submit button is pressed, a new query will be made using the inputs and the results displayed on the page.

Here is the code I have so far:

In "app.js", I make a connection to the database and render it to the page:

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    // make connection
    host: ...,
    user: ...,
    password: ...,
    database: ...
});

connection.connect();

//routes
app.get("/", function(req, res){

    var cmd = `SELECT * FROM myTable`;
    connection.query(cmd, function(err, result, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.render('home', {result: result});
    });
});
```

And in home.ejs, I iterate over each entry in result to create a row in the table:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th> ... </th>
        .
        .
        .
    </tr>
    <% result.forEach(function(entry) { %>
    <tr>
        <td><%= entry.column1 %></td>
        .
        .
        .
    </tr>
    <% }) %>
</table>
```

So the first part seems to be working (displaying all the data in the DB upon initial loading), but I am struggling to do the second part as I have no prior web development experience.

I currently have a  in the page to accept user input and a  associated with the form. However, I am not sure how I can use the user input inside myFunction() to perform another query to the database, and how to replace the current content of the table with the result of the new query.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: When you say you will have all the data on load, does your "filter" submission really need to make a round trip to the backend again? I would think your filter would only filter what the data the client already has? Could you give more details on what the filter is going to do?

Comment: @MatthewHarwood Actually I never thought about that point, but yes you are right, another query doesn't have to be made. I am only filtering out data that doesn't meet the requirements from the initial full result.

Comment: Hey buddy theres a few missing pieces in your question but I think my approach will work for you.  There will probably be a lot of follow up questions around templating client side and filtering the data.  These might be better suited as separate stackoverflow questions but leave them and I'll help guide ya.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so what you want to do is make client side filter of the data you already have in the view.

The problem is that the table is rendered server side, so how will you mutate the data on the client side after initial load?

The solution: set the data to a string on the window/global on render

```
<table id="results-table">
    <tr>
        <th> ... </th>
        .
        .
        .
    </tr>
    <% result.forEach(function(entry) { %>
    <tr>
        <td><%= entry.column1 %></td>
        .
        .
        .
    </tr>
    <% }) %>
</table>
<script>
  window.results = results;
</script>
```

after that lets make a search box and submit button inside your template:

```
<input type="search" id="filter-searchbar"/>
<button id="filter-submit-btn"> submit</button>
```

Let's add an event to listen to search and a handler to filter out the data:

```
const filterSearchBar = document.querySelector('#filter-searchbar');
const filterSubmitBtn = document.querySelector('#filter-submit-btn');

filterSubmitBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  // Next step.
})
```

Let's lets filter the `window.results` from the user's search input:

```
const filterSearchBar = document.querySelector('#filter-searchbar');
const filterSubmitBtn = document.querySelector('#filter-submit-btn');

filterSubmitBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const filteredResults = window.results.filter(result => {
    // Not sure what you wanna filter by but imagine that it's by a property name.
    return result.name === filterSearchBar.value;
  });
  // Final step
});
```

Final step is to rerender that data client side inplace of the table template:

```
const filterSearchBar = document.querySelector('#filter-searchbar');
const filterSubmitBtn = document.querySelector('#filter-submit-btn');

filterSubmitBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const filteredResults = window.results.filter(result => {
    // Not sure what you wanna filter by but imagine that it's by a property name.
    return result.name === filterSearchBar.value;
  });
  const resultsTable = document.querySelector('#results-table');
  results.innerHTML = `<pre>${JSON.stringify(resultsTable)}</pre>`

});
```

Hopefully you understand that I used `JSON.stringify` to just show you the output is filtered.  You'll need to do your own table templating at this point.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed response! When I set `window.results = result;` I get an error saying that result (on the RHS) is not defined. Do you know why that might be?

Comment: I figured it out! I realized that I can only access the `result` variable inside ejs so I am doing `window.result = \`<% result %>\`` instead.

Comment: Just some other things to think about. If this application is public you MUST sanitize the query going to the server.  If not bad actors could drop your database. Also setting data on the window isn't the best method of sending over data to the client.  It's prob better to create an API where you fetch via XHR.  I would suggest.  Obviously you could be just creating a prototype where none of this matters! Good luck!

Comment: In the last line, ` results.innerHTML = `<pre>${JSON.stringify(resultsTable)}</pre>\``, is `results` referring to the variable from app.js rendered to the page? I can dereference the variable with <%- %> but I can't modify it inside a <script> tag. Do you know how to work around this?

Comment: does your filter can you `console.log(filteredResults)` if so than use that to render a new table client side using dom manipulation clientside

Comment: Yes I can do console.log(filteredResults) and it logs the information to the console correctly. I understand that DOM manipulation is something like `table.innerHTML = ...`. Could you direct me to where I can learn more about doing that with what is logged in the console? Thanks so much again for the help :)